License conflicts in Blender shaders
The Blender source code contains the node codes under the GPL license for GLSL, and the exact same code in C++ in cycles for the Apache license. Can I port the Apache code to GLSL, and still use the Apache license? The codes are the same except for the differences in language syntax. For example:
GPL licensed code:
void mix_dodge(vec4 col1, vec4 col2, float fac, out vec4 outcol)
{
  outcol = col1;

  if (outcol.r != 0.0) {
    float tmp = 1.0 - fac * col2.r;
    if (tmp <= 0.0) {
      outcol.r = 1.0;
    }
    else if ((tmp = outcol.r / tmp) > 1.0) {
      outcol.r = 1.0;
    }
    else {
      outcol.r = tmp;
    }
  }
  if (outcol.g != 0.0) {
    float tmp = 1.0 - fac * col2.g;
    if (tmp <= 0.0) {
      outcol.g = 1.0;
    }
    else if ((tmp = outcol.g / tmp) > 1.0) {
      outcol.g = 1.0;
    }
    else {
      outcol.g = tmp;
    }
  }
  if (outcol.b != 0.0) {
    float tmp = 1.0 - fac * col2.b;
    if (tmp <= 0.0) {
      outcol.b = 1.0;
    }
    else if ((tmp = outcol.b / tmp) > 1.0) {
      outcol.b = 1.0;
    }
    else {
      outcol.b = tmp;
    }
  }
}

Apache licensed code:
ccl_device float3 svm_mix_dodge(float t, float3 col1, float3 col2)
{
  float3 outcol = col1;

  if (outcol.x != 0.0f) {
    float tmp = 1.0f - t * col2.x;
    if (tmp <= 0.0f)
      outcol.x = 1.0f;
    else if ((tmp = outcol.x / tmp) > 1.0f)
      outcol.x = 1.0f;
    else
      outcol.x = tmp;
  }
  if (outcol.y != 0.0f) {
    float tmp = 1.0f - t * col2.y;
    if (tmp <= 0.0f)
      outcol.y = 1.0f;
    else if ((tmp = outcol.y / tmp) > 1.0f)
      outcol.y = 1.0f;
    else
      outcol.y = tmp;
  }
  if (outcol.z != 0.0f) {
    float tmp = 1.0f - t * col2.z;
    if (tmp <= 0.0f)
      outcol.z = 1.0f;
    else if ((tmp = outcol.z / tmp) > 1.0f)
      outcol.z = 1.0f;
    else
      outcol.z = tmp;
  }

  return outcol;
}

Could I port the svm_mix_dodge codes to my OpenGL / GLSL shaders without having to use them under the GPL license, since the code would be very similar to the code licensed as GPL?
Note that these licenses apply to all blender nodes.
The codes were taken from this and this file.
The licenses can be found here and here.

Could you pls add a few links to the license pages of the different projects you are mentioning? This will increase the likelihood that someone looks into it and provides an answer.

I've added the links to the code and license information to the question.
